# Mysql GROUP BY subqueries takes too much time

Tags: mysql

I have this query which heavily uses three subqueries.

```
SELECT m.id AS id,
       m.restaurant_id,
       m.title_en AS title,
       m.description_en AS description,
       CONCAT('{"id":',m.id, ', "title": "',m.title_en, '", "description": "', m.description_en, '", "categories": ', '[',GROUP_CONCAT('{"id":',f.id,',"name": "',f.name_en,'"',',"description": "',f.description_en,'"',',"items": ',f.items,'}' SEPARATOR ','),']','}') categories
FROM menus m
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT c.id AS id,
          c.name_en AS name_en,
          c.menu_id AS menu_id,
          c.description_en AS description_en,
          CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT('{"id":',g.id,',"name": "',g.name_en,'"',',"description": "',g.description_en,'"',',"sizes": ',g.sizes,'}' SEPARATOR ','),']') items
   FROM categories c
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT i.id AS id,
             i.name_en AS name_en,
             i.category_id AS category_id,
             i.description_en AS description_en,
             CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT('{"name": "',s.name_en,'"',',"price":', si.price,'}' SEPARATOR ','),']') sizes
      FROM items i
      INNER JOIN items_sizes si ON si.item_id = i.id
      INNER JOIN sizes s ON si.size_id = s.id
      GROUP BY i.id) g ON g.category_id = c.id
   GROUP BY c.id) f ON m.id = f.menu_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING m.restaurant_id = 1 LIMIT 10;
```

This query results in something like

```
{id: "",
 title: "",
 desctiption: "",
 categories: {
               id: "",
               name: "",
               description: "",
               items: {
                   id: "",
                   name: "",
                   description: "",
                   sizes: { 
                           name: "",
                           price: ""
                   }
               }
          }
 }
```

However this query takes over 20 seconds to run which is quite huge. I suspect that the reason is the heavy use of sub-queries however I am not sure and can not find a way other than that to implement this complex query

**EDIT:**
There is a table menu having a title and description, a menu has many categories which in turn has a name and a description. A category has many items which in turn has many sizes What I am trying to achieve is an aggregation of all those in a json string through group concat it works and i have the correct results the problem is the time it takes which is over 20 seconds and is disastrous for the current application i am developing.

> menus(id:integer, title_en:string, description_en:string);
>
> categories(id:integer, name_en:string, description_en:description,
> menu_id:integer)
>
> items(id:integer, name_en:string, description:string,
> category_id:integer)
>
> items_sizes(id:integer, price:integer, item_id:integer,
> size_id:integer)
>
> sizes(id:integer, name_en:string);

**EDIT:**

results of EXPLAIN

> 1, PRIMARY, m, index, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, , 4060,
>
> 1, PRIMARY, , ref, key0, key0, 4, m.id, 98,
>
> 2, DERIVED, c, index, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, , 39961,
>
> 2, DERIVED, , ref, key0, key0, 5, c.id, 10,
>
> 3, DERIVED, s, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 1122, Using temporary; Using
> filesort
>
> 3, DERIVED, si, ref, item_id,size_id, size_id, 4, s.id, 338,
>
> 3, DERIVED, i, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, si.item_id, 1,

Comment: For an optimization query you need the explain plan and tables structure,not the downvoter

Comment: There is a table menu having a title and description, a menu has many categories which in turn has a name and a description. A category has many items which in turn has many sizes
What I am trying to achieve is an aggregation of all those in a json string through group concat 
it works and i have the correct results the problem is the time it takes which is over 20 seconds and is disastrous for the current application i am developing

Comment: try `EXPLAIN` on your query to get an explanation about where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: i edited the question providing more explaination

Comment: IF you remove LIMIT is it any faster?

Comment: it does not make any difference

Comment: Look here for how to get the explain plan,edit your question with the results http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: edited question with results of explain

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries are a huge disadvantage in this kind of case. If you have more than one Subqueries in your sql Query, the time for the query output will increase at an exponential rate as the number of subquery increases.

In short, Subquery will execute repeatedly for every parent row. Assume there are 50 rows in parent table, then the subquery will execute 50 times.

Take a look this link which described the problems in subqueries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html

> If the inner and outer queries return M and N rows, respectively, the execution time becomes on the order of O(M×N), rather than O(M+N) as it would be for an uncorrelated subquery.

Comment: what alternatives can i use ?

Comment: One dirty solution is to execute each subquery seperately and pass the output of subquery to it's parent query as `IN (?,?)`. Always try to limit the max number of subqueries to 1. If it exceeeds 1, you face increase in query execution time.